# jquery function not catching dynamically generated id

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a table whose rows are generated by an ajax query response like:

```
var inp = '<input id="new_po_qty" style="text-align:center" type="text" value="1">';
$('<tr id="new_po_item_row">').html('<td style="text-align:center">' + sku_id + '</td><td style="text-align:center">' + inp  + '</td><td id="new_po_cp" style="text-align:center">' + cost_price  + '</td><td id="new_po_total_cp" style="text-align:center">' + cost_price  + '</td>').appendTo('#new_po_body');
```

Now i wrote a jquery function to catch changes on the `inp` variable in table row. But the jquery function is not catching the changes i do in the input box.

Jquery function:

```
$('#new_po_qty').on('change paste', function(){
    alert('changes made.');
    $.niftyNoty({
        type:"primary",icon:"",title:"Start Adding Products.",container:"floating",timer:5000
    });
});
```

What i am i doing wrong with the function?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use event delegation:

```
$(document).on('change paste', '#new_po_qty', function(){
    alert('changes made.');
    $.niftyNoty({
        type:"primary",icon:"",title:"Start Adding Products.",container:"floating",timer:5000
    });
});
```

See [jQuery `.on()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/).